# How to render content within a custom twig function?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm getting prices and bookings from different sources in one flat booking table like this:

```
record    2014-06-07   2014-06-14   2014-06-21   2014-06-28
1           2000.00     2500.00       2500.00      3000.00
           array(3)     array(null)   array(2)     array(1)

2           3000.00     3500.00       3500.00      2800.00
         array(null)    array(1)     array(null)  array(null)
```

Now I need to render the columns with prices and bookings into a nice layout. So I wrote a custom twig extension and gave them prices and bookings as arguments.

So my question is: How can I render the result of the custom Twig_Function within the twig extension? Sometimes I need to render only the price and sometimes I need to render the price and 3 bookings within a week.

Before using the twig extension I tried to render a custom controller. But that was very slow because having lots of rows and columns in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it did not worked for me, because I was getting a circularReferenceException. I helped me with injection an existing Twig Enviroment. So my service definition looks like

```
app.twig.extension:
  class: App\AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
  arguments: ["@twig"]
  tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

An the constructor looks like this:

```
function __construct(\Twig_Environment $environment)
{
    $this->environment = $environment;
}
```

In the function then I use

```
public function myFunction()
{
    // logic...

    return $this->environment->display(extension, arguments)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject in you twig extension templating service. See [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services).

Your code will look like this:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigEngine;

class MenuExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
        /**
     * @var TimedTwigEngine
     */
    private $templating;

    function __construct(TimedTwigEngine $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('app_prices_bookings', [$this, 'pricesBookings'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
        ];
    }

    public function pricesBookings($prices, $bookings)
    {
        $this->templating->render('@App/App/prices_bookings.html.twig', $prices, $bookings);
    }
}
```

app/config.yml:

```
app.twig.extension:
    class: App\AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
    arguments: ["@templating"]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

And now you can use this function in twig:

```
{{ app_prices_bookings(prices, bookings) }}
```